# Why is my Singlton constant not staying constant

Tags: node.js, module, singleton

I am trying to create a singleton module that can store data.  I want to be able to edit this date only with setters or public functions and only access it with getters.

I was able to create a getter, setter and a set function.  However, I ran into a problem I cant explain when I tried to create a reset function.

I store my default settings in `const _defPorts`.

I then assign `let _myPorts = _defPorts`.  (I want to create a private variable `_myPorts` that is initialised with the constant values from `_defPorts`.

The problem is when I start setting new values, which I expect will only alter `_myPorts`, it seems to also change my `_defPorts` values.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong or how it is possible that my const value is being changed.  Because of this the reset function does not work.

In my `console.log` I am only displaying the value of `_defPorts` to show at which point it changes value.

I feel my problem is with the `setPorts` function but I do not know how to fix it.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

This is the Singleton Module I am trying to create:

```
'use strict'
let activeConfig = (function () {
  const _defPorts = {
    http: 80,
    https: 443,
    secure: false
  }

  let _myPorts = _defPorts

  let setPorts = function (value) {
    console.log('SP->', _defPorts)
    if (value) {
      Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
        if (typeof _myPorts[key] !== 'undefined') {
          _myPorts[key] = value[key]
        }
      })
    }
  }

  return {
    setPorts: setPorts,
    resetConfig: function () {
      console.log('RC->', _defPorts)
      _myPorts = _defPorts
    },
    get instance() {
      console.log('GI->', _defPorts)
      return this
    },
    get ports() {
      console.log('GP->', _defPorts)
      return _myPorts
    },
    set ports(value) {
      return setPorts(value)
    }
  }
})()
module.exports = activeConfig
```

This is the code I am testing it with:

```
'use strict'
const {
  ports,
  instance: activeConfig
} = require('./activeConfig/activeConfig')

console.log('1 ->', activeConfig)
console.log('2 ->', activeConfig.ports)

activeConfig
  .setPorts({
    secure: true,
    http: 8080
  })

console.log('3 ->', ports)

activeConfig.ports = {
  secure: true,
  https: 4444
}

console.log('4 ->', ports)
console.log('RESET')
activeConfig.resetConfig()
console.log('5 ->', activeConfig.ports)
```

This is the console log output:

```
GP-> { http: 80, https: 443, secure: false }
GI-> { http: 80, https: 443, secure: false }
1 -> {
  setPorts: [Function: setPorts],
  resetConfig: [Function: resetConfig],
  instance: [Getter],
  ports: [Getter/Setter]
}
GP-> { http: 80, https: 443, secure: false }
2 -> { http: 80, https: 443, secure: false }
SP-> { http: 80, https: 443, secure: false }
3 -> { http: 8080, https: 443, secure: true }
SP-> { http: 8080, https: 443, secure: true }
4 -> { http: 8080, https: 4444, secure: true }
RESET
RC-> { http: 8080, https: 4444, secure: true }
GP-> { http: 8080, https: 4444, secure: true }
5 -> { http: 8080, https: 4444, secure: true }
```

Comment: `const` only means that you can't reassign it to another object. `let _myPorts = _defPorts` sets them to the same object though. You'd need to make a copy of it if you want to make them independent. This would be an indirect dupe of correctly cloning an object.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you were totally right!
This solved my problem: let _myPorts = Object.assign({}, _defPorts)